NDSolve`FEM` 3D problem
I solved Laplace's differential equation in 2D with functions from the NDSolveFEM package and everything worked fine, but when I extended it to 3D, it doesn't work well.I have a spherical area, [0,Pi/2]x[1,2]x[Pi/4,Pi/2]. When I calculate the L1 and L2 norm, it seems that the finer the network, the worse the result. I tried to manually insert the boundary conditions into the matrices, I tried to discretize the area into hexahedron elements and tetrahedron elements, but nothing helped. The load vector should be fine, so there will probably be an error in the stiffness matrix, so either I'm making a bad mesh or I'm using some function incorrectly.
I do the mesh like this, where R is the list of points that make up my area and B is the matrix that is filled with the indices of the points that make up the tetrahedran element. Dirichlet and Neumann are defined by DirichletCondition and NeumannValue and since the load gives me correct, they should be correct. When creating the mesh, I must have access to set the number and type of elements. Mesh is defined like:
mesh = ToElementMesh["Coordinates" -> R, "MeshElements" -> { TetrahedronElement[B]}];


There is how I make my mesh
center = {0, 0, 0};
x1 = 0;
x2 = 1;
x3 = 2;
x4 = 0;
y1 = 1;
y2 = 2;
z1 = 0;
y11 = 0;
angle1 = 90 Degree;
angle2 = 0 Degree;
angle3 = 45 Degree;
angle4 = 90 Degree;
r1 = EuclideanDistance[{x1, y1, z1}, center];
r2 = EuclideanDistance[{x4, y2, z1}, center];
d[{x_, y_, z_}] = 1/(EuclideanDistance[{x, y, z}, center]); 
n[{x_, y_, z_}] = -1/(EuclideanDistance[{x, y, z}, center])^2;
nx = 4;
ny = 4;
nz = 4;
r = Subdivide[r1, r2, ny];
uhly = Subdivide[angle1, angle2, nx];
dlzky = Subdivide[r1, r2, ny];
uhly2 = Subdivide[angle3, angle4, nz];
R = {};
R = Flatten[
   Table[Table[
     Table[{dlzka Cos[uhol]*Sin[uhol2], dlzka Sin[uhol]*Sin[uhol2], 
       dlzka*Cos[uhol2]}, {uhol, uhly}], {dlzka, dlzky}], {uhol2, 
     uhly2}], 2];
B = {};
For[j = 0, j < nz, j++,
 For[i = 1, i <= (nx + 1)*ny, i++,
  If[Mod[i, (nx + 1)] != 0,
   AppendTo[B,
    {i + j (nx + 1)*(ny + 1), 
     i + (nx + 1)*(ny + 1) + j*(nx + 1)*(ny + 1), 
     i + (nx + 1)*(ny + 1) + j*(nx + 1)*(ny + 1) + 1, 
     i + (nx + 1)*(ny + 1) + j*(nx + 1)*(ny + 1) + (nx + 1)}]]
  ];
 For[i = 1, i <= (nx + 1)*ny - 1, i++,
  If[Mod[i, (nx + 1)] != 0,
   AppendTo[
    B, {i + (nx + 1)*(ny + 1)*j, (i + 1) + (nx + 1)*(ny + 1)*
       j, (i + (nx + 2)) + (nx + 1)*(ny + 1)*
       j, (i + 1) + (nx + 1)*(ny + 1)*(j + 1)}]]];
 For[i = (nx + 1)*(ny + 1), i >= (nx + 1) + 1, i--,
  If[Mod[i - 1, (nx + 1)] != 0,
   AppendTo[
    B, {j*(nx + 1)*(ny + 1) + 
      i, (i - 1) + (nx + 1)*(ny + 1)*
       j, (i - 1 - (nx + 1)) + (nx + 1)*(ny + 1)*
       j, (i - 1) + (nx + 1)*(ny + 1)*(j + 1)}]]];
 For[i = (nx + 1)*(ny + 1), i > (nx + 1) + 1, i--,
  If[Mod[i - 1, (nx + 1)] != 0,
   AppendTo[B,
    {i + j (nx + 1)*(ny + 1), 
     i + (nx + 1)*(ny + 1) + j*(nx + 1)*(ny + 1), 
     i + (nx + 1)*(ny + 1) + j*(nx + 1)*(ny + 1) - 1, 
     i + (nx + 1)*(ny + 1) + j*(nx + 1)*(ny + 1) - (nx + 1)}]]
  ]]
mesh = ToElementMesh["Coordinates" -> R, 
   "MeshElements" -> { TetrahedronElement[B]}];

R is a list of points, and B contains the indices of the points that make up the elements.
oblast6 = 
  triangulacia = 
   DelaunayMesh[Table[R[[i]], {i, 1, (nx + 1) (ny + 1)}]];
neumann = 
  NeumannValue[(-n[{x, y, z}]),
   x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == r2^2];
dirichlet = {
   DirichletCondition[t[x, y, z] == d[{x, y, z}],)x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == r1^2],
   DirichletCondition[t[x, y, z] == d[{x, y, z}],
    r1^2 <= x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= r2^2 && 
     angle3 <= ArcTan[z, x] <= angle4 && y == 0],
   DirichletCondition[t[x, y, z] == d[{x, y, z}],
    r1^2 <= x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= r2^2 && 
     angle3 <= ArcTan[z, y] <= angle4 && x == 0],
   DirichletCondition[t[x, y, z] == d[{x, y, z}],r1^2 <= x^2 + y^2 <= r2^2 && z == 0],
   DirichletCondition[t[x, y, z] == d[{x, y, z}], 
    RegionMember[oblast6, {x, y, z}]]
   };

There is solution
vd = NDSolve`VariableData[{"DependentVariables", 
     "Space"} -> {{t}, {x, y, z}}];
sd = NDSolve`SolutionData[{"Space"} -> {ToNumericalRegion[mesh]}];
bcs = InitializeBoundaryConditions[vd, 
   sd, {{dirichlet[[1]], dirichlet[[2]], dirichlet[[3]], 
     dirichlet[[4]], dirichlet[[5]], neumann}}];
methodData = InitializePDEMethodData[vd, sd];
pdeCoefficients = 
  InitializePDECoefficients[vd, sd, 
   "DiffusionCoefficients" -> {{IdentityMatrix[3]}}];
dpde = DiscretizePDE[pdeCoefficients, methodData, sd];
dbcs = DiscretizeBoundaryConditions[bcs, methodData, sd];
{l, s, d, m} = dpde["SystemMatrices"];
DeployBoundaryConditions[{l, s, d}, dbcs];
stationarySolution = LinearSolve[s, l];
ifun = ElementMeshInterpolation[mesh, stationarySolution];

This is L2 norm
L2 = Sqrt[(1/Length[R]*
   Sum[(stationarySolution[[i]] - uA[R[[i]]])^2, {i, 1, Length[R]}])]

uA je exactly solution, and it gives L2=0.020287765999267786, for 4x4x4 elements and L2= 0.022335419321148367 for 8x8x8 elements, but for more elements it should be lower.

You should post the code as code and not as an image; also post the complete code, what is dirichlet and what is B? Then there is not need to set this up as a time dependent problem when you just solve a stationary case. As soon as you change the load coefficient to be something else then 0, you'd need to set the diffusion coefficient to a - IdentityMatrix.
